# Find lost device without Gmail account configured and without SIM card

Tags: security, gps-tracking, lost-phone

I recently misplaced a phone that did not have gmail account configured and did not have a SIM card in it either. Is there any way I can track it ?

All of the tracking apps either require sending an SMS (needs SIM card) or OTA install(needs Gmail account).

I do have the IMEI number of the phone.

Comment: You can tell all the carriers of your country to track that IMEI number if its possible.

Comment: Looks like the only way you can track it is: If you see it somewhere, follow it. Sorry -- but what do you expect? Either you forgot some additional facts (WLAN turned on, some app is running and sporadically connecting something, whatever) -- or you expect some special feature hidden so well that not even the developers know of...

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way to track it without having it configured in some way to connect to a wireless source of data.  Without a SIM card you can't do that via a service provider and without having the Google account configured (and thus an authentication token that identifies your phone) you can't do it via WiFi (if you have it turned on).